# Postgis routes diagram point-to-point

Tags: postgis, route, centroids

I have a set of centroids to which are related a set of points characterized by linename.
[image: Centroids in yellow- They are overlayed points with a linename that is the number displayed around the centroid]

The table with the points contains these fields:

id ¦ linename ¦ lat ¦ lon¦

I would like to make a diagram joining centroids through lines. I should connect the points with the same linename in order to make routes through centroids and place the linename on the line lenght.

Probably i shoud select these points with the same lanename and build each linename-route drawing a line but i'm quite new in postgis. Somebody can help me?

Comment: Welcome to SE. I suggest you take a look at the [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) function. Am I correct in thinking that you want to draw a line between two points labelled N98 or 95A, for example?

Comment: Thank you for your gentle reply John! I've better explained my problem in this post "Drawing routes through centroids"